# Unreal Engine 4 How to read saved player data?

Tags: c++, multiplayer, unreal-4, online

I seem to have writing working fine now. But I am running into odd problems reading the data back. I want to iterate over the files so I tried this but I got an error in the log stating something about not having any files cached? I know I read that EOS works with cached data but I could not get this to work unless I called `EnumerateUserFiles` first. But now when I need to go back and read a second time calling EnumerateUserFiles then `GetUserFileList` again no longer retrieves the updated information. I cant believe we would have to manage the cache ourselves so I have to be missing something. I would think the EOS Plugin would handle the caching automatically so I figure I have to be missing something. How can I go about reading the data back now?

```
TArray<FCloudFileHeader> Files = {};
Cloud->GetUserFileList(*UniqueNetId.Get(), Files);
```